# Tefillin on the elbow in the history

Tags: history, tefilin

> משנה האומר איני עובר לפני התיבה בצבועין אף בלבנים לא יעבור בסנדל איני
>   עובר אף יחף לא יעבור העושה תפלתו עגולה סכנה ואין בה מצוה נתנה על מצחו
>   או על פס ידו הרי זו דרך המינות ציפן זהב **ונתנה על בית אונקלי שלו הרי זה
>   דרך החיצונים**
>   (Babylonian Talmud - Megila 24:)

Some of the interpretations say that בית אונקולי is the elbow (R.Chananel). Is this opinion supported by historical evidence? I mean, did we find in the history sects who put their Tefillin right there on the elbow?

Comment: Do you mean the inside of the elbow?

Comment: Probubly that what they mean.

Comment: I have not seen that Rabbeinu Chananel. Just Rashi, Sfas Emes, sefaria.org and Art Scroll that translate it as outside the sleeve of his garment.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking about R.Chananel opinion (which you can see here, in the second page - last line: http://www.gemaramarkings.com/daf/megillah/megillah-024.pdf)  rather than about Rashi opinion (which is by the way doesn't match the Rambam opinion too)

Comment: I have found the Rabbeinu Chananel  but the translation of אצילי ידיו in Sanhedrin does not seem to be elbow, the translation appears to be armpit. One of the translations into English from WordHippo is *extremity* which would seem to be on the hand. In order not to be the palm, that might be the back of the hand or on the lower arm.

Comment: When talking about Hebrew language, we have to distinguish between 4 layers of the language - known as "רובד לשוני" (https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F:%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99). The same word in different layers may have different meanings. In Chachamim Hebrew language it means elbow. In Modern Hebrew it means what you said. Click here to find 3 meaning in 3 layers: https://www.milononline.net/do_search.php?Q=%E0%F6%E9%EC%E9+%E9%E3%E9%E5

Comment: Rashi (Erchin 19;1): "אציל - מרפק". The Tosafoth say the same (Shabath 92;1) See also R. Bachye Devarim 11;2 that explains it at length.

Comment: OK thanks. I cannot follow it further. In any case, I do not know of anyone in history who would have placed it other than we do.

Comment: (B.t.w. Even assuming R.Chananel means to the armpit, I'll still have the same question: Where did we find in the history people to put their Tefillin in the armpit?)